# Is there a way to loop a specific part of bash script

Tags: bash, loops, shell

This is code I found, I would like to loop these commands every 2 minutes starting with `cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)`.

```
    #!/bin/bash
# Script: Check-Temp.sh
# Purpose: Display the ARM CPU and GPU  temperature of Raspberry Pi 2/3
# -------------------------------------------------------
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
echo "$(date) @ $(hostname)"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "GPU => $(/usr/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
echo "CPU => $((cpu/1000))'C"
```

Comment: You can just create a new bash script containing only the lines you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

execute your code then wait for 2 minutes

```
#!/bin/sh  
while true  
do  
  ##your code here  
  sleep 120  
done
```